# This JavaScript function isn't working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm currently developing a website and I have this snippet of Javascript code which works perfectly fine in Google Chrome, but doesn't execute in Firefox. When I remove this function, the other functions below this one works fine in Firefox so I believe it's not a Firefox version issue. (I've already updated Firefox to check).

My question is this. Is there anything obvious about this function which prevents Firefox from executing it?

Please let me know if you need more context to the code.

Thanks.

```
// go over each filter button
filterToggles.forEach(function(toggle) {

  let attrVal = toggle.getAttribute(['data-filter']); // find the filter attr
  let newVal = attrVal.replace(' ', '-'); // hyphenate filter attr val
  toggle.setAttribute('data-filter', newVal); // set filter attr with new val

});
```

Comment: Any errors from the console for clues?

Comment: What version of FF? 59?

Comment: what is `filterToggles` - a genuine Array? or something "Array-like"

Comment: as much as it looks ridiculous, that will work, @Kaiido, because the argument will be coerced into the string `data-filter` ...

Comment: @JaromandaX right...

Answer (score 0):

depending on the version of firefox, forEach may not work.
https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach